# Degree of continuous mapping via integral

Tags: homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

Let $f \in C(S^{n},S^{n})$. If $n=1$ then the degree of $f$ coincides with index of curve $f(S^1)$ with respect to zero (winding number) and may be computed via integral
$$
   \deg f = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{f(S^1)} \frac{dz}{z}
$$
Is it possible to compute the degree of continuous mapping $f$ in the case $n>1$ via integral of some differential form?

Comment: The short answer is: Take the $n$-form $\omega$ that generates $H^n(S^n)$. Then $\deg f$ is the ratio of $\int f^* \omega$ over $\int \omega$.

Comment: See the beginning of this article: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Brouwer_degree#References (Kronecker's definition: $$ \frac{1}{\operatorname{Volume} S^{n-1}} \int_{\partial K} f^* \omega $$

Answer (score 1):

You could find some useful information (try page 6) [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-9/issue-1/Fixed-point-theory-and-nonlinear-problems/bams/1183550974.full) and [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=BaQYYJp84cYC&pg=PA26&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_toc_r#v=onepage&q&f=false).